# how to reset google map marker pin style without assign a new pin element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps-markers

I need to reset markers scale to 1 after some event triggered. My current solution is assign a new pinElement to each marker. I was wondering if there is a better way to do that. I was thinking we can just access marker's content and change the pin's scale. I think my current way is not really efficient. But I have not found any example in google map api documentation.

```js
propWatch([() => props.typeFilter], (newValues, oldValues) => {
        filterMarkers();
//reset the pin for marker
        loader.load().then(async () => {
            const { PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
            allMarkers.value.forEach((m, i) => {
                const pinDefault = new PinElement({
                    scale: 1,
                });
                const pintDefault2 = new PinElement({
                    background: "#76ba1b",
                    scale: 1,
                    borderColor: "#137333",
                    glyphColor: "#137333",
                });
                // use the worker order count string from the title
                m.content = Number(m.workOrderCount) > 0 ? pintDefault2.element : pinDefault.element;
            })
        });
        allMarkers.value.forEach((m) => {
            m.setMap(null);
        });

        filteredMarkers.value.forEach(m => {
            m.setMap(map);
        });
        filterApplied.value = true;
    }
}, { immediate: true });
```